Plotly stacked bar chart percentage yaxis
I have a little problem with my bar chart.
The percentages on the yaxis are not sorted and stops in the middle instead on top.
How is that possible?
I also think its very strange that the yaxis is not 100%, it stops by 11.3 %
This is what my chart looks like:

In this image what it must do:

This is my code:
df1 %>% count(Tijden, Status) %>% mutate(pct=paste0(round(n/sum(n)*100, digits = 1), "%")) %>%  plot_ly(x = ~Tijden, y = ~pct, type = 'bar', name = ~Status, text=~pct,textposition  = 'auto', textangle = 0 ) %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = "", tickformat = "%"), barmode = 'stack')})

By adding the "%" pct=paste0(n, "%"), you put strings in y. While plotly seems to understand that the y's are percents when drawing the bars (strings treated as numbers), it likely doesn't when it comes to the yaxis ticks where strings are treated as categories which are sorted in lexicographical order and laid out on the yaxis as is. You need to put the percentage as numbers in y and add the "%" only for text.

@EricLavault
How can I get the % by text? Can you show me that?

You could create one column for the percentages you put in y (float), and one column for the percentages you put in text (string), and refer to these variables accordingly : ... %>% mutate(y=round(n/sum(n)*100, digits = 1), pct=paste0(y, "%")) %>%  plot_ly(x = ~Tijden, y = ~y, type = 'bar', name = ~Status, text=~pct, ...).

Ah nice, thats it. Thanks!!!

By adding the "%" pct=paste0(n, "%") and using it in plot_ly(x = ~Tijden, y = ~pct, ...), you put strings in y. While plotly seems to understand that the y's are percents when drawing the bars (strings treated as numbers), it likely doesn't when it comes to the yaxis ticks where strings are treated as categories which are sorted in lexicographical order and laid out on the yaxis as is.
To fix this, you could create one column for the percentages you put in y (float), and one column for the percentages you put in text (string), and refer to these variables accordingly in plot_ly() :
df1 %>%
  count(Tijden, Status) %>% 
  mutate(y = round(n/sum(n)*100, digits = 1), pct = paste0(y, "%")) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~Tijden, y = ~y, type = 'bar', name = ~Status, text=~pct, textposition = 'auto', textangle = 0 ) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "", tickformat = "%"), barmode = 'stack')})

